# Interpolate two sine waves with different time points based on cycle percent MATLAB

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have two sine waves with different time points as below:

```
t1=1:10;
y1=sin(t1);
per1=100./t1;

t2=1:12;
y2=sin(2*t2);
per2=100./t2;
```

As you can see, one of the `y` variables has 12 time points and the other one only 10. If we consider each range as one cycle, and express it as a percentage, I would like to put the sine waves with 10 and 12 time points onto a the same 0-100% scale, then sum them.

Using this technique, I will add two sine waves, not based on time but based on the percentage of the cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create some common axes, and use interpolation (e.g. `interp1`) to approximate values at all of these points. Then you can add them.

```
% Your data, but with smaller intervals so it doesn't look like junk!
t1 = 1:0.01:10; y1 = sin(t1); 
t2 = 1:0.02:12; y2 = sin(2*t2);
% Interpolation to the highest number of points
N = max(numel(t1), numel(t2));
y1interp = interp1(t1, y1, linspace(min(t1), max(t1), N), 'linear');
y2interp = interp1(t2, y2, linspace(min(t2), max(t2), N), 'linear');
% Put on a common percentage axes with N points
pct = linspace(0, 1, N);
% Plot (or do whatever else!)
figure; hold on;
plot(pct, y1interp, '--r');
plot(pct, y2interp, '--b');
plot(pct, y1interp + y2interp, '-k');
hold off;
```

Output

[image: output]

Note: You may want to read about [Nyquist's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) - by which you should consider increasing the common number of samples for interpolation, `N`, to perhaps twice what I've used..